# Cannot open load file: Not a directory, notmuch

Tags: autoload, load, notmuch

Does anyone see what's wrong in my attempt to run notmuch in emacs?

My attempt to run notmuch

```
helm-M-x notmuch: Cannot open load file: Not a directory, notmuch
```

My .spacemacs

```
(autoload 'notmuch "notmuch" "notmuch mail" t)
```

Notmuch installed and running

```
notmuch 0.28.2

GNU Emacs 26.1
```

Comment: If you have installed `notmuch` from the git-repository you have to setup your `load-path` to include the absolute path of the `notmuch/emacs` directory.

Answer (score 1):

I had to install notmuch in order to solve the problem.
Apparently I only had the [0]notmuch-runtime installed *but not* [1] notmuch itself.

Installing notmuch with `$ sudo pacman -S notmuch` was my solution.

[0] https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/notmuch-runtime/

[1] https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/notmuch/

Comment: Please explain, in your answer, how this answers the question. IOW, please elaborate.

Comment: Can you add more information to your answer?